# Interpretation of regression coefficient of logged variable (log X)

Tags: regression, logarithm, derivative

I am struggling to see why a one percent change in $X$ is associated with a $\frac{\beta_1}{100}$ change in $Y$ in the following model:

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \ln X + \beta_2 W + ... + u$.

It is clear to me that $\frac{\delta Y}{\delta \ln X} = \beta_1$

But then the professor wrote:

$\frac{\delta Y}{\frac{\delta X}{X}} = \beta_1$.

Why did $\delta \ln X$ turn into $\frac{\delta X}{X}$?

Is this a proper equality, or does this come from the Taylor approximation of $\ln Z \approx \frac{\Delta Z}{Z}$ around a neighborhood of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because $\frac{\partial \ln X}{\partial X} =\frac{1}{X}$, so by applying [the chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule): $$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X} = \beta_1 \cdot \frac{1}{X} \implies \frac{\partial Y \cdot X}{\partial X} =\frac{\partial Y}{\frac{\partial X}{X}} = \beta_1$$

To convert $\frac{\partial X}{X}$ to percent, you need to multiply by 100, so you need to multiply by $\frac{1}{100}$ on the right to balance that, which yields:

$$\frac{\partial Y}{100 \cdot\frac{ \partial X}{X}} = \frac{\beta_1}{100}$$

The quantity on the right-hand side is the change in $Y$ (in units of Y) associated with a 1% change in X.

Comment: When you use $\rightarrow$, do you mean that the left hands side tends to the right hand side?

Comment: No, it's just "implies". Let me fix that.

Comment: Thanks a ton! My confusion came from thinking that $\delta \ln X = \frac{\delta X}{X}$ was an approximation, since $\ln X \approx \frac{\Delta X}{X}$.