# Interpretation of log-level regression coefficients

Tags: regression, least-squares, logarithm

I am posting this question following [this other](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549239/interpretation-of-regression-coefficient-of-logged-variable-log-x/549249#549249) question I posted earlier today.

Suppose we have the following model:
$$\ln Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + ... + \varepsilon $$

Why is a marginal change in $X_1$ associated with a $\beta_1 \times 100$ percent change in the expected value of $Y$?

---

This is my reasoning process so far:

$$\frac{\delta \ln Y}{\delta X_{1}} = \beta_1$$

And because of the chain rule (I'm not sure about this part):
$$\frac{\delta \ln Y}{\delta X_{1}} = \frac{\delta \ln Y}{\delta Y} \frac{\delta Y}{\delta X_{1}} = \frac{1}{Y} \frac{\delta Y}{\delta X_{1}} = \frac{\frac{\delta Y}{Y}}{\delta X_1}$$

So if the change in $X_{1}$ were unitary then:
$$100 \times \beta_1 = \frac{\delta Y_i}{Y_i} \times 100$$

The RHS is the percentage change in $Y$. Therefore, an isolated unitary change in $X_{1}$ is associated with a $100 \times \beta_1$ change in the expected value of $Y$.

Comment: This logic seems right. What’s the issue that you are having with it?

Comment: Despite the seemingly correct logic, I was not sure it truly was the right way to think about it. Especially due to the term $\frac{\delta \ln Y}{\delta X}$ being expressed as a product of two derivatives. If you'd like, you can post a response saying that the logic is correct and I'll mark it as accepted.